# Loop invariants to figure the values of n, low, and high

Tags: java, loop-invariant

[image]

so, I'm supposed to use the information provided above the loop to figure what the values of **n, low, and high** are going to be without the need to know what is actually happening inside the loop. Can someone explain how can I use loop invariant to solve this example. The question is to find these values  `n=81` and `low =8` and '''high=9```. These are the correct answers for the question.

Answer (score 0):

We have three axioms:

- `low` and `high` are allowed to change inside the loop, but `n` is not.
- `low + 1 <= high` and `low * low < n <= high * high` must both be true in each iteration of the loop.
- `high - low` must decrease for each iteration of the loop

I'm not sure what your textbook says is the proper method for deriving the output - reference it - but from my perspective, the problem-solving method is thus:

1. Compare the solution to the initial values

   - `n` does not change (which is good, the `@updates` implies it's not supposed to)
   - `low` increases from 3 to 8

     - note that 8^2 = 64
   - `high` decreases from 41 to 9

     - note that 9^2 = 81
   - the axioms given in the comment above the loop are maintained here

     - (8 + 1) <= 9
     - 8^2 < 81 <= 9^2
2. Since the axiom says `@decreases high - low`, this must be the driving force of change within the loop. Either `high` must decrease, or `low` must increase.

   - see that `high` has decreased, and `low` has increased. This must be the direction they're individually supposed to change in. Note that doing either of these things will fulfill the `@decreases` demand, because math.
3. The `@maintains` axioms define the limits of this change. `low` cannot exceed `high` (and `low * low` cannot exceed `n`), and `high * high` cannot ever be less than `n`.

   - i.e. when to *stop* changing `low` or `high`. If a change would violate one of these, then don't make that change.

We can conclude that the intention of this loop is to set `low` and `high` such that

- they differ by exactly 1
- `n` is between `low`^2 and `high`^2 (inclusive of `high`^2)

or, in other words, to set `low` and `high` respectively to the two roots of the perfect squares which `n` sits between.

---

From this, we can write the following code:

```java
while (low < high - 1) {  // will terminate when low == high - 1
    // check the @maintains for `low`. The first @maintains was just checked by the
    // loop, so we just have to check the next @maintains. If increasing `low`
    // would not make the @maintains false, then we can increase `low`.
    if ((low + 1) * (low + 1) < n) {  
        low++;    // this will always decrease the value of (high - low), per @decreases
    }
    // check the @maintains for `high`. Same as above, but since `low` might
    // have changed since the last time we checked, we need to double-check
    // that we can still decrease high without problems.
    if ((high - 1) * (high - 1) >= n && (high - 1) > low) {
        high--;   // this will always decrease the value of (high - low), per @decreases
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is to find these values ``` n=81``` and ```low =8``` and '''high=9```. These are the correct answers for the question. What are the steps to find these answers?